# Maintain Session between ASP Pages called by Ajax

Tags: ajax, session, asp-classic

I've an odd problem.

I've a classic ASP application, which is working very well.

On another classic ASP application, I try to make Ajax requests to the first one, but the session variables are not maintained.

I tried two things :
- if I call page1.asp which makes a Response.Redirect to page2.asp, session object is empty on page2.
- if I call page1.asp and in case of success call page2.asp, same result.

Of course, this is working well if not called by Ajax, so page1 and page2 are OK.

$.ajax() or native XHR, same results.

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you,

EDIT : using Server.Transfer and setting all parameters in page1 did the trick, but did not explain to me why :(

Comment: You can't share session state between 2 different applications.

Comment: When you do AJAX request there is no session.